# How to condense large ascii art from a file python3

Tags: python, ascii

I have looked for a solution to this problem for some time, and I do not think it is possible to do what I want.

I have a file containing large ascii art (100+ lines long each picture), and I was wondering if I could print each pic. to the console in only a couple lines (for an arbitrary number, let's say 5).  I am using python3.

Edit: Here is an example of what I want to print to the console (color doesn't matter):
[Reese's Example v2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFomP.png)

Is there a way I can print the above image to the console and have it remain that size in the console?  It has about 100 lines of ascii text.

Thanks!

Comment: By reducing art from 100 lines to 5 the art could suffer, to the point of not being recognizable. Can you please edit the question and add example art and expected output?

Comment: Perhaps you could resize the image prior to executing your script. You could also have a peek at marching squares algorithm (or at least be inspired by it) if the image becomes unclear.

Comment: @nosklo I updated the post

Comment: @Electrimatics try my answer, it reduces the ascii art to 5 lines. You can edit the number to reduce it to any number of lines.

Comment: The example (Reese's Image) looks more like colorized block art - do you know if it is using ansi codes?  My guess is that grabbing arbitrary characters from an arbitrary lines would produce a scramble of color-code fragments & block-shape characters:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art#ANSI_art and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: @jgreve I updated the post again.  The original example was a bad one.  I uploaded a new example in ascii.

Comment: Ok, that looks simpler to work with.  :-)  What do you get with @nosklo's code?  And... who is your target user? Do you need to see these yourself? Are you writing previews for somebody?  When you say "console" I'm assuming you mean a linux command prompt - what is your console?  (if linux, can you just set your font size=2 and just do $ cat reeses_example.txt  ? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
art = '''
                 ***          ***
              ***....**     **...***
             **........** **.......**
      ***    **..........*.........**    ***
   **.....**  **..................**  **.....**
 **.........**  **..............**  **.........**
*..............*   *..........*   *..............*
 **..............*   *......*   *..............**
   **..............** *....* **..............**
     *......................................*
   **..............**........**..............**
 **..............*    *....*    *..............**
*..............*      *....*      *..............*
 **.........**        *....*        **.........**
   **.....**         *....*           **.....**
      ***          **....*               ***
                 ** * * *
'''.splitlines()
for line in art[::len(art)//5]:
    print(line[::len(art)//5])
```

The results:

```
     ...**..*
 ...* .....**...*
 *..... .**....*
 .....  .* .....*
 *..   *.    *.*
```

Comment: illustrates your comment - but its ugly :P

Comment: @usr2564301 I just updated the picture.  I realize it was a poor example, and I just put a better one up.

Comment: @Electrimatics did you try my answer

Comment: @nosklo I did.  It went okay.  I did find another ascii art generator that I think would work better than downsizing the original one, but I will keep your answer in mind for another time.  Thanks!

Comment: @Electrimatics it seems my answer is correct for this question, if you feel like it, please accept it to close the question. Thanks

Comment: @nosklo I meant to do so yesterday but forgot (was pretty busy).  Thanks!